# how to use combine loops and use in subprocess?

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary, subprocess

my_dict has the 1000 values sample -

```
{0: {'Id': 'd1', 'email': '122as@gmail.com', 'name': 'elpato'},
 1: {'Id': 'd2', 'email': 'sss@gmail.com', 'name': 'petoka'},
 2: {'Id': 'd3', 'email': 'abcd@gmail.com', 'name': 'hukke'},
 3: {'Id': 'd4', 'email': 'bbsss@gmail.com', 'name': 'aetptoka'}}
```

This code by using name in `my_dict` and creating json data and json files of it by using faker library random data is generated.

Here by running `1.py` 4 json files are created.

i.e., `elpato.json`, `petoka.json`, `hukke.json`, `aetptoka.json`

Here is `1.py` :

```
import subprocess
import json
import faker

for ids in [g['name'] for g in my_dict.values()]:
         fake = Faker('en_US')
         ind=ids

                sms =  {
                     "user_id": ind ,
                     "name": fake.name(),
                     "email": fake.email(),
                    "gender": "MALE",
                    "mother_name": fake.name(),
                    "father_name": fake.name()
                        }

        f_name = '{}.json'.format(ind)
        print(f_name)
        with open(f_name, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(sms, fp, indent=4)
```

for grabbing email :

```
for name in [v['email'] for v in my_dict.values()]:
    print(name)
```

need to use  name and email loops in subprocess

output I need :  in `f_name` 4 json files that has been created above should load.

```
subprocess.call(["....","f_name(json file)","email"])
```

I need to loop the subprocess so that subprocess will run into loop by calling both f_name and email in a loop. Here it should loop for 4 times as 4 json files are created and 4 emails are in dict.

Comment: why subprocess? why not just apply threading or asyncio ? also, `for idx in range(1)` makes no sense

Comment: is there any way by using subprocess. and updated

Comment: You need to realize a benefits from using subrocess against other approaches. If you don't realize the advantages - don't use it

Comment: i am going to use curl in subprocess. so need to use subprocess only. or any method by which it should be ruuning on cmd